# Get the device width in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

**Is there a way to get the users device width, as opposed to viewport width, using javascript?**

CSS media queries offer this, as I can say

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    /* ... */
}
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:960px) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This is useful if I'm targeting smartphones in landscape orientation. For example, on iOS a declaration of  `max-width:640px` will target both landscape and portrait modes, even on an iPhone 4. This is not the case for Android, as far as I can tell, so using device-width in this instance successfully targets both orientations, without targeting desktop devices.

**However**, if I'm invoking a javascript binding based on device width, I appear to be limited to testing the viewport width, which means an extra test as in the following,

```
if ($(window).width() <= 960 && $(window).height <= 640) { /* ... */ }
```

This doesn't seem elegant to me, given the hint that device width is available to css.

Comment: Try this website to know the correct dimensions of your device. http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Comment: `Modernizr` can help you do this "the clean & generic way": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935686/modernizr-media-query-doesn-t-work-when-resize-browser . Regarding the 1st comment: you may want to google "Modernizr vs <otherLib> media query" to find out what works best for your use case

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You can get the device screen width via the `screen.width` property.
Sometimes it's also useful to use `window.innerWidth` (not typically found on mobile devices) instead of screen width when dealing with desktop browsers where the window size is often less than the device screen size.

Typically, when dealing with mobile devices AND desktop browsers I use the following:

```
 var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

Comment: I've noticed this doesn't work as expected on Android 2.2 native browser. If I am not at a 1:1 scale it can report much wider widths (as wide as the page can be) which is a bit frustrating.

Comment: This returns 980 on Chrome Beta on Android and 1024 on the Android Browser on a HTC vivid.

Comment: @Alex These are the browsers' default viewport widths.  If you use a viewport meta-tag with `width=device-width` you should get the actual value.

Comment: window.innerWidth is returning 980 on Iphone (Chrome/Safari). How is that? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> made no difference.

Comment: On retina iPhone, device width (applied via meta tag) matches screen.width (320px), but on an Android device with double pixel ratio, device width is half of screen.width (e.g. 360px/720px). I'm looking for a way to detect the scaled device width (i.e. 320px on a 640px width double pixel ratio device) that works on both iOS Android. Braden's answer below seems to resolve this..

Comment: How does this have so many upvotes? `var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;` returns 667 on iphone 6 AND 6 Plus. This solution does not work correctly.

Comment: This will not work. Say for example you have a desktop with 1920x1080 resolution but your window is resized to 600x400. This will return 600.

Comment: @lan S makes no sense, however, I have posted a more reliable solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713246/2118665

Answer (score 73):

One issue with Bryan Rieger's useful answer is that on high-density displays, Apple devices report screen.width in dips, while Android devices report it in physical pixels. (See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html .) I suggest using `if (window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 960px)').matches) {}` on browsers supporting matchMedia.

Comment: This seems like a much better solution and actually uses CSS media queries. I wonder what the browser support is for this across mobile platforms?

Comment: @CarlZulauf, I've done testing on a half-dozen devices with excellent results. If window.matchMedia, use the above, else test screen.width.

Comment: Would this be the correct usage?

 `if (window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 960px)').matches) {
  var winW = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
 } 
 else {
  var winW = screen.width;
 }`

Comment: Unfortunately, norsewulf, matchMedia can only give you booleans. `var isMobile; if (window.matchMedia) {isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 960px)').matches;} else {isMobile = screen.width <= 960;}`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work without the scaling set to 1:1 as a base ... `var isMobile = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 960px)').matches || screen.width <= 960;`

Comment: For Browsers not supporting `matchMedia()` there is a polyfill: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia) practically all browsers, including mobile, support window.matchMedia()

Comment: It looks like browser support has improved across theboard in 2018.

Answer (score 14):

I just had this idea, so maybe it's shortsighted, but it seems to work well and might be the most consistent between your CSS and JS.

In your CSS you set the max-width value for html based on the @media screen value:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){

    html { 
        max-width: 480px;
    }

    ... more styles for max-width 480px screens go here

}
```

Then, using JS (probably via a framework like JQuery), you would just check the max-width value of the html tag:

```
maxwidth = $('html').css('max-width');
```

Now you can use this value to make conditional changes:

```
If (maxwidth == '480px') { do something }
```

If putting the max-width value on the html tag seems scary, then maybe you can put on a different tag, one that is only used for this purpose. For my purpose the html tag works fine and doesn't affect my markup.

---

**Useful if you are using Sass, etc**: To return a more abstract value, such as breakpoint name, instead of px value you can do something like:

1. Create an element that will store the breakpoint name, e.g. `<div id="breakpoint-indicator" />`
2. Using css media queries change the content property for this element, e. g. "large" or "mobile", etc (same basic media query approach as above, but setting css 'content' property instead of 'max-width').
3. Get the css content property value using js or jquery (jquery e.g. `$('#breakpoint-indicator').css('content');`), which returns "large", or "mobile", etc depending on what the content property is set to by the media query.
4. Act on the current value.

Now you can act on same breakpoint names as you do in sass, e.g. sass: `@include respond-to(xs)`, and js `if ($breakpoint = "xs) {}`.

What I especially like about this is that I can define my breakpoint names all in css and in one place (likely a variables scss document) and my js can act on them independently.

Answer (score 13):

You should use

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

It is regarded as cross-browser compability, and is the same method that jQuery(window).width(); uses.

For detailed information have a look at: https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Comment: Is this the size of the full device width or of the window at the time that the site is loaded? I think it is the latter, from my initial tests.

Answer (score 10):

check it

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
  // window width is at least 500px
} else {
  // window width is less than 500px
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 10):

`var width = Math.max(window.screen.width, window.innerWidth);`

This should handle most scenarios.

Comment: Math.max(window.innerWidth); will give you the width, including scrollbars in FireFox, Edge and Chrome. document.documentElement.clientWidth; will give the width inside any scrollbars in those browsers. In IE 11, both will show the width including scrollbars..

Answer (score 10):

You can easily use

`document.documentElement.clientWidth`

**Update**

For example:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('result');
el.innerText = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    // do what you want
    el.innerText = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}, true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <body>
      <div id="result"></div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @TimDiekmann You're right. Just added one simple example to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the method Bootstrap uses to set its [Responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints), the following function returns xs, sm, md, lg or xl based on the screen width:

```js
console.log(breakpoint());

function breakpoint() {
    let breakpoints = {
        '(min-width: 1200px)': 'xl',
        '(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)': 'lg',
        '(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)': 'md',
        '(min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px)': 'sm',
        '(max-width: 575.98px)': 'xs',
    }

    for (let media in breakpoints) {
        if (window.matchMedia(media).matches) {
            return breakpoints[media];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lumia phones give wrong screen.width (at least on emulator).
So maybe `Math.min(window.innerWidth || Infinity, screen.width)` will work on all devices?

Or something crazier:

```
for (var i = 100; !window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: ' + i + 'px)').matches; i++) {}
var deviceWidth = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya mybe u can use document.documentElement.clientWidth to get the device width of client and keep tracking the device width by put on setInterval

just like

```
setInterval(function(){
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        console.log(width);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Just use onresize. For example document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onresize = function()

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, there is a library called [breakpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/breakpoints-js) which detects the max-width as set in CSS and allows you to use it in JS if-else conditions using <=, <, >, >= and == signs. I found it quite useful. The payload size is under 3 KB.