# how to get screen height and width in Dart

Tags: dart

I've seen that Dart has a Screen class but cannot use it to get width and height of the target device mobile browser screen.

I've tried several ways to get it, but it always fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with [Screen.available](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Screen.html#available) (eg. `window.screen.available.height`) or [`window.innerHeight`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Window.html#innerHeight) if `window.screen.height` does not work.

See [this answer of *Get the device width in javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850319/634863).

Comment: I was unable to use Screen.available [it's not static and there is no default constructor for Screen]. fwiw Screen docs are garbage.. and there is no screen object. But I was able to get it to work with window.innerHeight but still can't understand why it's not Window et all. Thanks Alexandre

Comment: You access _screen_ with `window.screen`.