# Media Queries in JQuery ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How could I insert a media query into the calling of an ID in Jquery?

Example:

```
$('#idname')
$('@media (max-width: 767px) { #idname }')
```

So basically it called the `#idname` with that media query. Is this possible with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you're saying is that you're only selecting the element if it's at most `767` pixels you can do it by selecting the element and then checking its `width`, if there are multiple elements you can use `.filter` as such:

```
// ids are unique, but this also works for classes
var els = $("#idname").filter(function(i, el){ 
     return window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches; 
});
els; // only matching elements
```

Comment: does `$(el).width() > 767;` correspond to css media query value ?

Comment: @AminMeyghani sorry, you're right, this checks if the width of the element is more than 767 pixels not if the width of the page is less than that, I'll update the answer. I need to get some sleep :S

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense...

If you want to use CSS media queries inside JavaScript:

Try using the `mq` method from modernizr.

example: [Modernizr Media query doesn’t work when resize browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935686/modernizr-media-query-doesn-t-work-when-resize-browser)

another example: http://craftedpixelz.co.uk/blog/conditional-js-with-modernizr-mq/

i.e.

// load modernizr mq method (build a custom download containing the media query method from http://modernizr.com/download/

then once it is loaded to the page (in script tag), you can do:

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) { // do stuff here }
```