# How to detect screen size for responsive web design?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I googled this and got a [quirksmode site](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest.html) that gives you your screen size.  Pulling up the console I see that `screen.width` and `screen.height` are directly available from the window object.

I want to do the detection in pure JavaScript to get started.  Can I use this property across all devices and browsers - mobile, tablet, PC and Chrome, Safari, IE, Firefox.

I don't care about the view port changing due to re-sizing etc.  Just the actual size of the screen which does not change.

I was hoping there was a single property I could check across devices and browsers.

Here is some general info by [wikipedia on responsive web design.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Comment: "I want to do this in pure JavaScript to get started." — Don't do that. [Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead.

Comment: My question - `How to detect screen size for responsive web design?` - Can I use media queries to get this value?

Comment: — Why would I recommend that you use them if you couldn't?

Comment: RWD is done with mediaqueries in 90% of webprojects. It gets quite messy, quite fast, when trying to do a responsive design with pure javascript. At least use an framework like bootstrap or similar if you want to do it purely with javascript.

Comment: I will likely use media queries, but I want to log the x and y dimensions of each users screen when they first login.  This is what I meant by getting started with JS.  This way I can characterize what screens I'm working with before writing the CSS media queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`screen.width` is the property your are looking for.

Answer (score 54):

Take a look at [Get the device width in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript)

Media Queries work in js too:

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 768px)').matches) {}
```

Another way would be:

```
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me after long hunch.
These attributes below provide responsive sizes based on new tab size.

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `screen.width` & `screen.height` will detect the width and height of the screen and not necessarily the users browser width/height. So this may not provide an accurate reading if the user resizes the browser.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

Another way would be to use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. Regardless of the device/screen, this would provide the actual browser width/height. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth

A bit of testing would determine which one would be most suitable for your requirements.

You may also want to read about Layout Viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Layout_viewport