# conflicting media queries iPhone X

Tags: html, css, media-queries, iphone-x

I have the following media queries. The first one is for certain screens below a certain width. The second is specifically for the iPhone X. Is it possible to override the first media query when it is an iPhone X only? The following does not seem to work

```
@media (max-width: 449px) {
    h1.question { padding: 20px 0px; }
}

@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { 
        h1.question { padding-top: 50px !important; }
}
```

Comment: How are you testing? Actual device or emulator?

Comment: Hi Robert, on the emulator.

Comment: try using: -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio (notice *-min*).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`.

*The -webkit-device-pixel-ratio feature is specified as a  value. It is a range feature, meaning that you can also use the prefixed -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio and -webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio variants to query minimum and maximum values, respectively.* ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio))

As a test of this I set up the following fiddle, which will output `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` ([with credit to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829123/how-to-get-the-values-that-are-used-in-media-queries-e-g-device-width)). Also stack snippet below.

https://jsfiddle.net/3w5rq8pj/10/

**I tested this on several devices with the following results:**

- Actual iPhone 7 Plus / Result **3**
- Macbook Pro with Retina Display / Result **3**
- Lenovo Thinkpad (ie) / Result **0**
- Emulated iPhone 6 Plus on BrowserStack via Macbook Pro with Retina / Result **3**
- Emulated iPhone 6 Plus on BrowserStack via Lenovo Thinkpad / Result **3**

In all these cases the Browserstack emulators returned the proper results (which honestly suprised me).

I also re-ran all the tests but removed -min from the query in the javascript, and every single test case returned 0.

```js
function guess() {
  var ls, l=0, h=8192, c=parseInt((l+h)/2), i=20;
while (i > 0 && (c - l >1) && (h - c>1)) {
  i--; // Shouldn't take more than 13 guesses, but in case of bugs!
  if (window.matchMedia('(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: ' + c + ')').matches) {
    l=c; ls=0;
  } else {
    h=c; ls=1;
  }
  c = parseInt((h+l)/2);
}
c -= ls;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "min pixel ratio: " + c;
}

guess();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```