# @angular/flex-layout How To: different class based on screensize?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Is there a way to have @angular/flex-layout change the **class** based on screen size?

I know I can do this:

```
<div fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
```

and this:

```
<div fxFlex="22"    fxFlex.md="10px" fxHide.lg>
```

etc.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="myWideClass" class.xs="myNarrowClass">
```

Is there any way to do this kind of thing - change the class based on the screen width?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript

Comment: This post isn't relating to angular nor angular/flex-layout

Comment: Yes it is. I have fxFlex.md and fxHide in my examples. That's angular/flex-layout isn't it? At least I thought it was.. I haven't used flex box outside of angular/flex-layout so maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was refering to the first comment ;) Please check out my answer, this should solve you problem and is the angular way to go

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there is a way!

Just try this:

```
<div [ngClass.xs]="'myNarrowClass'"
     [ngClass.md]="{'myWideClass': true}"></div>
```

Here are the docs

[ngClass API Responsive](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API#responsive-features)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If someone is looking for a way to add a class if it is bigger than xs for example, you could do:

```
<div [ngClass.gt-xs]="'myNarrowClass'"></div>
```

Comment: Solution above looks better for my case.