# Determining small devices: max-width really better than max-device-width / screen.width?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

What is an efficient way to detect small devices in javascript?

I tried to do that with media queries, and I tested `max-width` and `max-device-width`.

Everybody says that `max-width` should be used.

But in my test with Chrome on a Moto G5 `max-device-width` indicates the mobile device much better:

```
window.innerWidth: 980 // could be a monitor
window.innerHeight: 1394

screen.width: 360 // small, indicates a mobile device
screen.height: 640

window.devicePixelRatio: 3

(min-width: 500px): true
...
(min-width: 1200px): true // could be a monitor

(min-device-width: 300px): true
(min-device-width: 400px): false // small, indicates a mobile device
```

`min-device-width` seems to correspond to `screen.width`. Both distinguish the mobile device from a monitor.

Since everybody is suggesting to use `max-width` I wonder:

How can you use that to distinguish mobile device from a monitor?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Refer below link I think this link is useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` / `min-width`  / `max-width` should be used. `screen.width` is the width of the entire screen which may be bigger than the window.

In order to get usable values from `window.innerWidth` / `min-width`  / `max-width`, you have to put this in the head section of the html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```