# How would I remove a picture if user is a mobile device

Tags: html, css, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSOTG.png)I need to remove a picture (using css) if a device visits that is a mobile user. I’ve tried media queries with the display:none and many other things And nothing. Maybe I’m just not using proper syntax or putting it in the right spot? Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "*Maybe I’m just not using proper syntax*". We can't possibly know unless you share your code. But a media query with `display: none` is indeed the way you should be going about it.

Comment: Show us your code so that we can see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @obsidian Age  Ok sorry about that guys. Thought i had my code in there but i guess not. There should be a link to my code now.

Comment: @yong Quan Ok sorry about that guys. Thought i had my code in there but i guess not. There should be a link to my code now.

Comment: Please provide code as text. Code as images are unhelpful as we then have to re-type out the code. Please read about [MCVE]  and [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/4665) to help get actual code into your questin.

Comment: How can you use <img> withing <head> ! As far i know , <head> contains only meta data like link, style....
You can do it with multiple way, Easiest way is using media query with display: none
You can use js function getboundingclientrect, screen.width e.t.c to know the device width and according to width you can set your css class.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript

 And your <style> tag should place within head section.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've posted, the stylesheet is targeting the class:

```
.post .sc_image img
```

but your code example only shows an image tag without the parent containers that have the **.post .sc_image** classes.

You'd expect to see the image inside some divs (etc) like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="sc_image">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

For your example to work correctly, remove **.post .sc_image** out of your css.

However, I'd guess that these other classes are because your complete code has more to it than just the  tag sitting by itself. With that in mind, I would assume that some other style within your application is overwriting the display:none property.