# How to change href and onclick function of a download button based on device width

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am wanting to change the download link based on a device width (mobile, tablet, pc) What js would I need to accomplish this?

```html
<a href="url" onclick="function"; class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger download">Download</a>
```

Comment: This is invalid html for a start `onclick="function";` Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript) answer you learn that there are many method of obtaining the device width in js. One of the best them is the one below:

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
  // window width is at least 500px
} else {
  // window width is less than 500px
}
```

So you can do something like (resize window to test for small size):

```js
var a_element;

function changeHref() {
    const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );
    a_element = document.querySelector(".download");
        
    if (mq.matches)
        a_element.href = "http://www.google.com";
    else
        a_element.href = "http://www.duckgogo.com";

}
changeHref();
console.log(a_element.href);
```

```html
<a href="url" onclick="function"; class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger download">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use width in javascript. Have 3 anchor tags, show only 1 at once using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery_breakpoints) width

```
<a onclick="function1()"; class="showOnDesktopOnlyUsingMediaQuery">Download Desktop</a>
<a onclick="function2()"; class="showOnTabletOnlyUsingMediaQuery">Download Tablet</a>
<a onclick="function3()"; class="showOnMobileOnlyUsingMediaQuery">Download Mobile</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish without even using JavaScript. [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) are designed exactly for this type of thing. You make 3 separate `<a>` tags, and alternate between `display:inline` or `display:none` based on the media queries. For example, on a mobile screen, both the desktop and tablet links will be set to `display:none` while the mobile link will be set to `display:inline`.

But if you really need to use JS though, you can do something like the following.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="link-change" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger download">Download</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link-change");

var mobile = "url-mobile";
var tablet = "url-tablet";
var desktop = "url-desktop";

link.onclick = function(){
   if(screen.width < 768){
      link.href = mobile;
   } else if(screen.width < 1024){
      link.href = tablet;
   } else {
      link.href = desktop;
   }
}
```

You may need to change the breakpoints (1024px, 768px) I just used those off the top of my head for this example.

Comment: by far the clean answer