# How to know what device been used to view website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With CSS, you can use @media to manipulate website style depending on the screen size.

Can I do the same with JavaScript?

situation:

if website opens using a phone:

```
    id.style.width='500px';
```

if website opens using a tablet:

```
    id.style.width='800px';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). Like this:

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 600px)').matches) {
  console.log("this window bigger than 600px");
}
```

You should get `matches` key for Boolean value. Because `window.matchMedia('(min-width: 600px)')` returns an object.

```js
console.log(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 600px)'));
```