# I want to use JavaScript to change the background image on a website when the device is small

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, background

I built a webpage with a Parallax feature.  I used javascript to disable the text part on small screens, but there is no picture.  I want to use JavaScritp to swap the larger picture (1500pixels) for a smaller one(500px).  I copied the class in called home, changed the name to mobilehome and added the smaller image.  Here is the code javascript:

```
/* disable paralax scrolling */
var ismobile = /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
if (ismobile){

 // bypass parallax effect
 background()
 }

  //change background pictures
  function background () {
  var background1 = document.getElementById("home");
  background1.target.classlist("mobilehome")};
```

It doesn't work, any advice?

Comment: Instead of background1.target.classlist("mobilehome"), can you try using
background1.classlist.add("mobilehome"). @terere

Comment: thanks, this didn't change the image.   I am using chrome, and shrinking the image.  Its weird, if I do this, I get the same image .jpg image as apposed to the .webp image that js told it to use.  When I put it on the web and use my phone, I get nothing.  I just tried this code on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In this topic they suggest using methods to find out the device size

[Get the device width in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript)

It seems like you could use `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and then use the returned value to decide wether you want to change the background displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need an event listener that will make a callback to a function that will handle the change of the bg depending on the `innerWidth` of the window.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 500){
    // change bg to a smaller one
  }
  else{
    // change bg to a bigger one
  }
})
```

If you run the below code as a full page and resize it you will see how the width of the screen is been updated every time.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  console.log(window.innerWidth)
})
```